# jQuery Save all dragged element from droppable box (after a button click)

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I would like to save dragged element from droppable area after button click. Example: i have a box where i can drag & drop few elements and then click 'SAVE' to get all dragged elements in a array list.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="draggable" id="widget-1">
  drag box 1
</div>
<div class="draggable" id="widget-2">
 drag box 2
</div>
<div class="draggable" id="widget-3">
 drag box 3
</div>

 <div class="droppable" id="box-1">
      <p>This is Box-1</p>
 </div>

 <div class="droppable" id="box-2">
      <p>This is Box-2</p>
</div>

 <a href="#" onclick="saveValue()">SAVE </a>
```

Thanks in advance.